# update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I am facing the problem while running the java program from command line.
I have openjdk-6-jdk installed in my linux system and still shows the error relates with the openjdk-7-jdk. 
Initially i have jdk 7 installed in my system but ater i have removes it but still facing problem while running the application.

after running the cammand

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

it shows warning as follows

update-alternatives: `warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling,` it will be updated with best choice.
There is only one alternative in link group java: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/bin/java`
Nothing to configure.

what should I do?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming you installed the OpenJDK6 with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

In Ubuntu 64 bit, make sure the paths are valid for your installation (change if using 32bit version):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Setup update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Alternatively, make sure the correct version is checked for both Java and compiler:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

List the installed Java alternatives with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list java
sudo update-alternatives --list javac
```

Answer (score 0):

**update java alternatives:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question about a warning?

Answer (score 0):

If you install openjdk 8 in docker. Maybe you need to install "software-properties-common"

```
apt-get update && apt-get install apt-file -y && apt-file update && apt-get install software-properties-common
```

And then you install openjdk 8 and setup update-alternatives with end number = 3

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" 3
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" 3
```