# update-alternatives : update java path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I want to update the java path.After running the command

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I get following :

```
        Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
        ------------------------------------------------------------
          0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1         auto mode
          1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode
        * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java          1         manual mode
```

Now I want to update the path for `jdk1.7.0_25.`

what should i do?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want your `PATH` environment variable contain the path to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin`?

Comment: The problem is about the updating the java path I want to update that path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/bin/java thats it

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _java path_. `update-alternative` lets you chose which executable is called when you type `java` in your console. So you can not _update the path for `jdk1.7.0_25`_ but you can update the path of `java` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java`. So if you select `2` and afterwards type `which java` it gives you the previously selected path.

Comment: I have set all the java paths using the bellow link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609083/update-alternatives-warning-etc-alternatives-java-is-dangling Now I just want to change the path from /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/bin/java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`man page`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) there is no parameter for `update-alternatives` to change an entry. So you would have to remove your entry `2` with `--remove` and `--install` it again. Then you might have to `--config` the command again to point to the correct directory.

Alternatively, you can manually change the entry in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt it ask for the selection number??

"Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:"

Comment: Yes it ask for the selection.The problem is about the updating the java path I want to update that path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/bin/java thats it