# Installing eclipse mars on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm

I just downloaded the  linux 64 bit tar for eclipse mars. When I try and run the installer it gives me the following message

```
Version 1.6.0_31 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. 
Version: 1.7 or greater is required.
```

I am on java version 1.8. See

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Where does it get the 1.6 version of java?

```
.cshrc.mine 

setenv $JAVA_HOME /path/to/Java8
setenv PATH /path/to/Java8/bin/:$PATH
```

Also

```
$ java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
  // Other props
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_65-b17

java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609083/update-alternatives-warning-etc-alternatives-java-is-dangling

Answer (score 0):

Try specify the JDK/JRE path by adding the following two lines into the beginning of your eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
[your-path-to-java-executable]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse.ini file you should point to java8

```
-vm
/opt/jdk18025/bin/javaw.exe
```