# Unable to downgrade java version from 1.8 to 1.7 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, java-8, java-7

I have an amazon EC2 Bitnami tomcat ubuntu instance running and it has default JDK as 1.8 .
I have installed oracle-7 jdk via `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` 
Now, I tried to change the default version from 8 to 7.
I ran the commands mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609083/update-alternatives-warning-etc-alternatives-java-is-dangling) . 
They run succesfully. But when I do `java -version` , I still get :

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Can someone please tell me how can I make the default java version to 1.7 ? 
Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default`. And reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here. Please find below the steps required to install Java 7 JDK on your system and modify the Bitnami environment for changes to take effect. As an extra step before starting to modify your system, I recommend you to create a server backup.

- Install Java 7 JDK on your system by running the commands below. It should be installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
  ```
- Create a backup of the files that you need to modify

  ```
  cp /home/bitnami/.bashrc /home/bitnami/.bashrc.bck
  sudo cp /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh.bck
  sudo cp /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh.bck
  sudo cp /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.sh /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.sh.bck
  ```
- Set `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to point to the Java 7 installation directory adding the lines below at the end of the `/opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh` file

  ```
  # Set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Java 7
  PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:/opt/bitnami/java/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin:/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:$PATH"
  export PATH
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/lib:/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib:/opt/bitnami/apache2/lib:/opt/bitnami/common/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  ```
- Modify the `JRE_HOME` variable from `JRE_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java` to `JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in file `/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh`
- Modify the `JAVA_HOME` variable from `JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java` to `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in both `/opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh` and `/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` files
- Restart all the Bitnami services using the `ctlscript.sh` script

  ```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
  ```
- Load the environment and check the Java version by running the commands below

  ```
  . /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh
  java -version
  ```
- Visit the Apache Tomcat manager application to check the Java version currently running. You should see a "Server Information" section similar to the one below

[image: Tomcat Manager App Server Information]

Additionally, you can modify the `/home/bitnami/.bashrc` file for the new environment to be automatically loaded every time that you connect to your server by adding the line below to the end of the file

```
    . /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh
```

Best regards,

Gonzalo