# Elasticsearch installation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, installation

As per the install wiki  [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html#install-targz]            I have the  elasticsearch-5.4.3 installed.

./bin/elasticsearch gave the following error  :

```
    Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version    
    from /usr/bin/java does not meet this requirement
```

So I have downloaded the latest version of java as well in the same directory as that of elasticsearch.

But running the following command still errors out

```
    ./jre1.8.0_151/bin/java ./elasticsearch-5.4.3/bin/elasticsearch
```

with error message :

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class ..elasticsearch-5.4.3.bin.elasticsearch
```

What could be the remedy for this ?

Comment: This question be better closed as it is wrong as pointed out by M2E67 in the comments below . I'm unable to do so at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install your java (version 8+) and set $JAVA_HOME variable or download java. use update-alternative to set default java.

[update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609083/update-alternatives-warning-etc-alternatives-java-is-dangling)

then, install elasticsearch from rpm file and config /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html

now, you can start elasticseach service by executing :

```
service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: Actually I do not have the required permissions to replace the default java

Comment: ./elasticsearch-5.4.3/bin/elasticsearch is not a java executable file. it's only an bash script

Comment: Realized just now whatever you pointed out. Should have looked into the script much earlier. Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Possibility 1: don't start with java, run elasticsearch directly

step 1: set the $JAVA_HOME to your latest 1.8 java installation

step 2: run the command ./bin/elasticsearch

Possibility 2: permission issue

step 1: set SELinux to permissive mode

step 2: run the installation command from the same user from which you have 
          downloaded and extracted the elasticsearch packages.

Comment: I do not have the permissions to change $JAVA_HOME , nor SELinux either.  Tyring to change SELinux throws the error : setenforce: SELinux is disabled